# Parallel Processing in Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

For an example I have 3 virtual machines in a Resource Group.

I want to Start those virtual machines in parallel.

Lets say, 1 VM takes 3 mins to Start, so for 3 VMs it would take 9 mins. Now I want those VMs to start in parallel such that in around 3 mins all the 3 VMs should get started.

After much R&D I didn't find any solution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Start-Job` and `Wait-Job` to implement this. Here is a PowerShell script for you.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$VMs = @(@{"Name"="vm1";"ServiceName"="srv1"};@{"Name"="vm2";"ServiceName"="srv2"};@{"Name"="vm3";"ServiceName"="srv3"})
$jobs = @()
foreach ($vm in $VMs) 
{ 
    $params = @($vm.Name, $vm.ServiceName, $cred) 
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
        param($Name, $ServiceName, $cred) 
        try{
            $acct = Get-AzureRmSubscription
        }
        catch{
            Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
        }
        start-AzureVM -Name $Name -ServiceName $ServiceName 
    } -ArgumentList $params  
    $jobs = $jobs + $job 
} 
Wait-Job -Job $jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

The above code is for classic deployed VMs. If you are using ARM deployment, you can use the following script instead.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$VMs = @(@{"Name"="vm1";"ResourceGroupName"="rg1"};@{"Name"="vm2";"ResourceGroupName"="rg2"};@{"Name"="vm3";"ResourceGroupName"="rg3"})
$jobs = @()
foreach ($vm in $VMs) 
{ 
    $params = @($vm.Name, $vm.ResourceGroupName, $cred) 
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
        param($Name, $ResourceGroupName, $cred) 
        try{
            $acct = Get-AzureRmSubscription
        }
        catch{
            Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
        }
        start-AzureRmVM -Name $Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
    } -ArgumentList $params  
    $jobs = $jobs + $job 
} 
Wait-Job -Job $jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: I tried running the script, but it seems that the VMs are getting started one after the other in a loop, and why does I have to Login-AzureRmAccount for every loop. ???

Comment: How did you know the VMs start one after another? Did you see it on the portal? I have tested a script with `Login-AzureRmAccount` out side of the loop, but it only work for the first VM. And, you can see that, the `Login-AzureRmAccount` is surrounded by try-and-catch, so, if it's already login, it will not login again.

Comment: You have to Login-AzureRMAccount in each job because each job is in a separate process (requiring it's own authn).  PS didn't always work this way but it does with the new 1.x cmdlets.  So the try/catch is probably unnecessary there...

Comment: @JackZeng Thanks a lot. I am done with what i wanted. :)

Comment: @bmoore-msft Thanks!! I got it.